# Hybridization of Ester Oxygen

Tags: organic-chemistry, hybridization

I'm on the email list of an Organic Chemistry help website, and they sent out this problem:

http://orgomadesimple.com/june-9-email-practice-problem/

This got me thinking:

- What if the nitrogen here was replaced with another oxygen atom?
- Would it still be $sp^2$ hybridized?
- Can oxygen molecules hybridize?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Changing that nitrogen to an oxygen would make an ester, right?

Comment: It's similar, but not quite the same. I'd call it borderline.